# python3 prime factor function I wrote is not working as I intended

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function

```
def primeF (n):
    x = 2
    factors: List[int] = []
    while (x < n):
        y = 2
        flag = 0
        while (y < x):
            if (x % y == 0):
                flag = 1
            y = y + 1
        if (n % x == 0 and flag == 0):
            factors.append(x)
    x = x + 1
    return factors
primeF(6)
```

There is always an error when I run this code but I'm not exactly sure why. The error messages are:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/User/untitled/EulerQs.py", line 41, in 
>       print (primeF(6))   File "C:/Users/User/untitled/EulerQs.py", line 38, in primeF
>       factors.append(x) MemoryError

I don't know what this means. I'm using PyCharm if that makes any difference.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Indentation problem: `x = x + 1` is not in the while loop, so `factors.append(x)` blows up your memory. Try printing values to catch errors like this--you'll see that `factors` just grows and grows with the same prime (probably 2) repeated indefinitely. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Yes, just as @ggorlen pointed out, you can see that `x` is never getting incremented in your loop, so when `x<n` becomes True, the loop gets into a indefinite loop as it is running for `while(True)`, also there are no exiting conditions.

Comment: Another thing you can do, is `while (x < n):` to `while (x <= n):`. That way the function also finds the prime factors when n is a prime.

Comment: thank you all for your responses! i wouldnt realize it without you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the reason for the crash is that the outer while loop never ends because the increment of `x` is outside of that loop. Just change the indentation to place `x = x + 1` inside the loop.

Another thing that is useful, is to automatically write out the result for a range of numbers. Then you will see the function gives an empty list each time `n` itself is a prime. Therefore, in the stop condition of the outer while loop, you should also allow for `x == n`.

Changing this, the code looks like:

```py
def primeF (n):
    x = 2
    factors = []
    while (x <= n):
        y = 2
        flag = 0
        while (y < x):
            if (x % y == 0):
                flag = 1
            y = y + 1
        if (n % x == 0 and flag == 0):
            factors.append(x)
        x = x + 1
    return factors

for i in range(11):
    print(i, "has as prime factors:", primeF(i))
```

Output:

```
0 has as prime factors: []
1 has as prime factors: []
2 has as prime factors: [2]
3 has as prime factors: [3]
4 has as prime factors: [2]
5 has as prime factors: [5]
6 has as prime factors: [2, 3]
7 has as prime factors: [7]
8 has as prime factors: [2]
9 has as prime factors: [3]
10 has as prime factors: [2, 5]
```

Some ideas to further improve the program:

- In an if-test, brackets are not always necessary; it is custom to leave them out to make thing more readable.
- In most programming languages, flags are called booleans, with values True and False. Also, giving them meaningful names helps a lot in understanding a program.
- Now you test every `x` smaller than `n` first to be a prime and then whether it is a divisor. If you first test for being a divisor, you win some time by not needed to check for primeness. Also, you can break out of the loop as soon as you found out `x` is not prime.

Here is the code with the suggested changes:

```py
def primeF (n):
    x = 2
    factors = []
    while x <= n:
        if n % x == 0:
            y = 2
            x_is_prime = True
            while y < x:
                if x % y == 0:
                    x_is_prime = False
                    break
                y = y + 1
            if x_is_prime:
                factors.append(x)
        x = x + 1
    return factors
```

Comment: thank you for the fast response and the well explaned solutions. you are a great help